# Protecting other circuits from Geiger power supply

Tags: high-voltage, circuit-protection, buck-boost, transient-suppression, geiger-muller-tube

I'm designing a Geiger counter power supply that boosts 3.3 V to 500 V.

The circuit is a basic voltage booster.

3.3 V power line is directly connected to inductor where high voltage is generated. How can i protect the 3.3 V line = other devices connected to it, from high voltage transients generated in the inductor? Or is this even a issue?

My initial thoughts were using TVS diode before the voltage booster.

Comment: Why start with 3.3 V? Is that really the highest you have available?

Comment: 5v is available too, but 3.3v is already enough to make the circuit work.

Comment: What Finbarr's getting at is, 500:3.3 = 151.515 times as much voltage.  So to get 1mA out at 500V, 151.515mA would be drawn from 3.3V (ignoring about 20% loss.)  At 5V this current drops to 100mA plus losses - so higher voltages are easier to boost.

Comment: If your Geiger tube is drawing 1 mA, your health is in danger.

Comment: You don't need 1mA with a Geiger tube, they need maybe 100uA when there's a pulse, average current is much less. There are circuits online using 3V (see http://techlib.com/science/geiger.html).

Answer (score 0):

> *Or is this even a issue?*

It's not an issue with any boost converter circuit that I've ever seen.

Comment: This is propably the case, but most of the geiger counters i know are standalone units powered from batteries and are not connected directly to other circuits than their own. This one is going to be added to a bigger system with other circuits powered from the same source.

Comment: It's still not a problem @zerobeat